# Regular expression in Javascript to validate US phone number

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using `/^\d{3}\ ?-? ?\d{3}\ ?-? ?\d{4}$/;` to validate US phone numbers. Can anyone tell me how to modify this expression to make `()` optional on the first set of numbers.

For example: it should work for `(123)234-2345` , `123-345-4567` , `123 - 345 - 4567` , `123345-6789`

Answer (score 2):

Area code with or without braces

```
(?:\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})
```

optional `-` with optional spaces around it

```
(?: *- *)?
```

3 digits

```
\d{3}
```

and 4 digits

```
\d{4}
```

and all together now

```
^(?:\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})(?: *- *)?\d{3}(?: *- *)?\d{4}$
```

Comment: @melpomene Thanks for this hint, fixed.

Comment: @melpomene Ouch, embarrassing :$

Comment: @melpomene I hope, I'm old enough to stick with it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
/^\(?\d{3}\)? ?-? ?\d{3} ?-? ?\d{4}$/
```

Comment: after your second d{3} '\' is missing

Comment: No, there is no \ missing. Why are you asking me about your expression instead of trying my answer?

Comment: Because mine and yours is same except the '\'

Comment: No, it isn't. Mine doesn't contain `^(?`.